# Join on 3 different table takes time to fetch data

Tags: iphone, performance, sqlite

I am applying join query to fetch data from database on my iPhone app.
See my query
`"select A.a1, A.a2, B.b1, B.b2, C.c1, C.c2, from A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.a3 = B.b3 AND A.a4 = B.b4 LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON A.a5 = C.c3 Where A.a6 = '%@'"`

Here A contains more than 30K records, B has 20K records and C contains 200 records.
Is there any way to reduce the time taken to fetch the data?

NOTE : This query returns correct result.

Comment: On probable solution is to have custom paging as I guess you will not be showing all the records to user at a time on iphone screen. Paging will take some efforts to implement but that will be the best solution for performance of the application.

Comment: Actually, query returns 100 records max out of thousands, so I dont think paging will be a good option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use column indexes in the table. Following links point to as to how to create the indexes in Sqlite database.

1. [creating the index](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html)
2. [Same question answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862771/sqlite-indexing-performance-advice)

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried indexing Table A ? if not try it..
it might be a way to reduce the time to fetch data..
Warning : using Index in wrong place may affect your performance